# GooglePlay Game Service onLeaderboardScoresLoaded always has empty ScoreBuffer

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am using the GooglePlay game service for adding a Leaderboard in my game (actually, several leaderboards). Signing in to GooglePlayGameServices works, as well as submitting a score to a given Leaderboard-id. I checked this using a OnScoreSubmittedListener. The result is ok, the score is there.

When trying to retrieve the top scores for a given id using 'loadTopScores', the OnLeaderboardScoresLoadedListener gets called with STATUS_OK, one entry in the LeaderboardBuffer (I checked this entry, it is the exact same leaderboard-id I previously submitted the score to) and alway zero entries in the LeaderboardScoreBuffer. I could not find a solution to this problem. One thing that seems odd is that in the LeaderboardBuffer entry, the player rank is set to -1. But I couldn't find out what that means.

thanks in advance for any insights on this problem =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the problem myself finally =) It was rather easy. Since the services utilize one's google+ account, you have to set the permissions properly. Under "settings" -> "accounts" -> "google" -> "google+" -> "apps with google sign-in" is an entry for my game. There I had to allow uploading of scores to be public. Once I did that everything works fine for me.